# Client side validation does not working in edit page in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using client side validation plugin in my application. When I am validating a new from its working but when I am validating edit form its not working.

If anyone had done something similar, please suggest me how to proceed.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $("#group_name").validate({
   rules: {
    "group[name]": {
  required: true
},
"group[contact]": {
  required: true
},
"group[contact_phone]": {
  required: true
},
  },

   messages: {
  "group[name]": {
      required: "Required"
     },
  "group[contact]": {
  required: "Required"
     },
   "group[contact_phone]": {
   required: "Required"
     },
       },

   onfocusout: function(element) {
      this.element(element);
       },

        });
</script>
```

Comment: It need some more inputs, place html too and console error, if any